# how to trigger "online" event manually

Tags: javascript, html, offline

I have

```
$(window).on('online', function() { console.log('online'); });
```

And I'm trying to fire it on page load with

```
$(window).trigger('online');
```

Is there any way to do this without jquery? For example:

```
window.addEventListener('online', function() { console.log('online'); });
window.createEvent...?
```

Comment: Yup. `$(window).on("load",function(){ $(window).trigger("online") });` http://jsfiddle.net/UszZW/ my guess is in your actual code you have a timing issue resulting in the `.trigger()` never happening.

Comment: edited my question, take a look

Comment: So you want custom events without jQuery? i'd suggest instead just having a function that you execute.

Comment: like that, i mean. couldn't find appropriate documentation